# Send php array of device tokens to Urban Airship push

Tags: php, curl, notifications, urbanairship.com

I am very suck. I am trying to send to a php array of device id's with urban airship. I am using the first example found [here](https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/91072-simple-ios-broadcast-using-php-api-v3). Everything works, with `"audience"=>"all"`. Every registered device gets hit. I need to make a query of a database, that has a bunch of device id's in it, and send to those device id's. What do I change "audience"=>"all" to so I can do that. I have tried everything!

Here is the code incase the link breaks:

```
<?php
 define('APPKEY','XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'); // Your App Key
 define('PUSHSECRET', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'); // Your Master Secret
 define('PUSHURL', 'https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/');

 $contents = array();
 $contents['badge'] = "+1";
 $contents['alert'] = "PHP script test";
 $contents['sound'] = "cat.caf";
 $notification = array();
 $notification['ios'] = $contents;
 $platform = array();
 array_push($platform, "ios");

 $push = array("audience"=>"all", "notification"=>$notification, "device_types"=>$platform);

 $json = json_encode($push);

 $session = curl_init(PUSHURL);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_USERPWD, APPKEY . ':' . PUSHSECRET);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, True);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, False);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json', 'Accept: application/vnd.urbanairship+json; version=3;'));
 $content = curl_exec($session);
 echo $content; // just for testing what was sent

 // Check if any error occured
 $response = curl_getinfo($session);
 if($response['http_code'] != 202) {
     echo "Got negative response from server, http code: ".
     $response['http_code'] . "\n";
 } else {

     echo "Wow, it worked!\n";
 }

 curl_close($session);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched to the PHP 2 library for Urban Airship and I was able to send to individual device tokens. I was also able to read tokens out of an array, and assign the array value as the target. Version 2 found [here](https://github.com/urbanairship/php-library2/).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what device OS you are trying to send to. Via their documentation here:

http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/api/v3/push.html#atomic-selectors

you will need to set the correct device type to it's corresponding ID. For example:

android:

```
"audience" : {
    "apid" : "b8f9b663-0a3b-cf45-587a-be880946e880"
}
```

ios:

```
"audience" : {
    "device_token" : "C9E454F6105B0F442CABD48CB678E9A230C9A141F83CF4CC03665375EB78AD3A"
}
```

Comment: For whatever reason, that format did not work either. I finally used the PHP 2 library from Urban Airship. It had a lot of extra dependencies to install, but worked right away. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found a possible solution for this from urban airship help center... They suggest this. And its working for me.

You can send to multiple device tokens or APIDs in a single request. I would suggest using our new API v3 and batching up your requests. There are a couple ways to do this:

1) Send to multiple devices in one payload

`curl -v -X POST -u "<AppKey>:<MasterSecret>" -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/vnd.urbanairship+json; version=3;" --data '{"audience" : {"OR": [{"device_token":"<DeviceToken1>"}, {"device_token":"<DeviceToken2>"}, {"device_token":"<DeviceToken3>"}]}, "notification" : {"alert" : "Hello iOS devices!"}, "device_types" : ["ios"]}' https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/`

OR

2) Put multiple payloads together in one batch

`curl -v -X POST -u "<AppKey>:<MasterSecret>" -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/vnd.urbanairship+json; version=3;" --data '[{"audience": {"device_token": "<DeviceToken1>"}, "notification": {"alert": "Hello, I was sent along with a batch of other pushes!"}, "device_types": ["ios"]}, {"audience": {"device_token": "<DeviceToken2>"}, "notification": {"alert": "I was also sent with a batch of other pushes!"}, "device_types": ["ios"]}, {"audience": {"device_token": "<DeviceToken3>"}, "notification": {"alert": "Me three!"}, "device_types": ["ios"]}]' https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/`